# designing a hibernate dao

Tags: java, hibernate, dao

I am using following code

```
 TestDAO {

    Session session = null;

    public TestDAO() {
        this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }

   //...more code create,update ...
  //each method starts a transcation using  "tx= session.beginTransaction();"
```

}

1)Now should i commit the transcation using tx.commit for a fetch operation too or only for save/update operation?? 
2)Should i create a seperate instance of TestDAO every time i need?Or should i create a singleton class that returns a single instance of DAO everytme?Will this have a problem?

Comment: What does the title "analysing time complexity of a binary treee" have to do with your question?

Comment: Sorry, i added that by mistake.Changed it now

Answer (score 3):

1. You don't need tx.commit() for fetch operation. That is only needed for any save, update or delete. Close the session after data fetching.
2. If your application connect to only one database then use of single DAO is better. Spring framework encourages this. You will find more details about this on the following link

   [Don't repeat the DAO!](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao/index.html)

Comment: i am fetching the session object from  factory using hibernate util class [HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()], Do i need to close session???

Comment: @akshay: Session should be closed after unit operation. Here unit operation means CRUD operation. So, if you fetch data the steps should be 1. open session 2. fetch data 3. close session.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions should not be the responsibility of the DAO, those really need to be controlled at a higher level. A DAO should be something that does queries and updates without being aware of the bigger picture, calls to DAOs can be grouped within an object like a Spring service or EJB session bean which is responsible for deciding what needs to go together in a transaction. This makes your DAO code more reusable since it doesn't have to know as much about the context in which it's operating.

Look at how Spring does it (in the sample applications like petstore that come with Spring), or better, look at the King/Bauer Hibernate-JPA book, which has a chapter on creating DAOs.

Comment: Ok, if i start the transcation outside dao, should should i commit it only for update/insert or also for select??

Comment: This answer is right but poorly worded. The sequence is that some higher-level code begins the transaction, then one or more DAOs are called, then some higher-level code commits the transaction. So the DAOs themselves should not begin or commit transactions, but you should them of them being *inside* or enclosed by the transaction.

Comment: @nathan:Is this Java Persistence with Hibernate book @http://www.amazon.com/Java-Persistence-Hibernate-Christian-Bauer/dp/1932394885

Comment: @akshay: The answer to your followup is yes. You should close transactions rather than leave them lying around.

Comment: @all:i am fetching the session object from factory using hibernate util class [HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()], Do i need to close session???

Comment: @akshay: Yes, you need to close the session at some point. Some people use a servlet filter to open and close sessions. I would suggest looking into Spring if you haven't, it makes hibernate session management painless.

Comment: @akshay: and yes, that's the right book. It's an essential reference for Hibernate.

Comment: @all: what about singleton ?Shoul i make it singleton?

Comment: @akshay: it shouldn't have any mutable state, so it could be a singleton. The link in MAK Ripon's answer is a good place for examples, btw, look at that too.